# Azure Devops - Conditions issues in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 3 stages in my pipeline, and now i would like to had conditions for stages:

- Step #1 is triggered by default except if a PROD or SWINT variable were added during a manual build
- Step #2 is triggered by default except if a PROD or UNIT variable were added during a manual build
- Step #3 is always triggered

I tried a lot of different solutions but the best I can do is having a working solution without the possibility of canceling manually the run...

Any ideas ?

```
stages:
 - stage: Step1
   condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['PROD'], ''), eq(variables['SWINT'], ''))
   jobs:
     - template: ...     
     - job: Step1
       ...

 - stage: Step2
   condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['PROD'], ''), eq(variables['UNIT'], ''))
   jobs:
   ...

 - stage: Step3
condition: and(succeeded(), in(dependencies.Swints.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped'), not(canceled()))   
   jobs:
   - job: Step3
     pool: ...
     ....
```

Here is the issues:

- Adding condition overwrite the implicit default value 'succeeded()' so I have to add it, otherwise i cannot 'cancel' manually the build.
- When step2 is 'skipped' due to a PROD variable set, I would like to run step3 but it fails. To resolve this i have to replace condition by always() but in this case, the manual cancel is not taken into account.
- I would like to have step2 running on manual build when SWINT is added, step1 should be ignored/skipped then step2 should run and also step3. But during the run i would also allow manual 'cancel' to work....

**Addentum 1**:
Updated to the following solution, i think that is would be the correct strategy, it works when i set isProd value to false.
So now, i need to have a correct evaluation on this PROD.
It's a variable passed at queue time by the user, adding variable named PROD and set a value (i.e: 1). Doesn't look like to work. I would need a runtime evaluation but it seems that is should not be coded in this way.

When i set value: false, it works as i expect, and the evaluation expression

```
eq(variables['PROD'], '')
```

returns false or true when i use it into as a condition depending if i set PROD or not at queue time. I don't understand why the expression doesn't work when i use it in variables section.

```
variables:
- name: isProd
  value: $[eq(variables['PROD'], '')]

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], false)}}:
    - stage: Units
```

**Addentum 2**:
Trying a new strategy:

```
 - ${{ if eq(variables['PROD'], '' )}}:
   - stage: Step1 

 - ${{ if eq(variables['PROD'], '' )}}:
   - stage: Step2 

 - stage: Step3
```

But it still doesn't work, i cannot trig step1/step2 by adding variable PROD when i run it manually.

Here is my old condition

condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['PROD'], ''), eq(variables['SWINT'], ''))
When i set PROD with the value 1 from web interface queue build feature, it makes a false and the stage is skipped. The same test from IF statement above stages doesn't react in the same way apparently. The evaluation doesn't work, i don't know why.

Comment: It looks like the main issue is to distinguish from my stages: skipped because of condition and canceled from pushing button.

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know the issue is resolved from your side. Would you consider marking your answer please? It may help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Comment: It is not resolved.

Comment: You posted an `answer` which made me think the issue was resolved. May I know what you mean by `PROD or SWINT variable were added during a manual build`? Have you  explicitly defined the values for the variables `PROD` and `SWINT` in the pipeline? Do you expect the conditions of 3 stages to be evaluated without being dependent on one another?

Comment: Sorry for posting more information as an answer instead of editing. its fix
When a push is done on the main branch, all steps are processed without any conditions. What i'm trying to do is allow user to launch a manuel build using the queue build feature, adding a variable named PROD or SWINT and set value to 1.

When i do this, i can evaluate the value of this variable when i use it in conditions (but using conditions creates issue on cancel that i described at the beginning). So i tried an other strategy but in this case thses variables are not evaluated at all and i don't understand why.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the inputs. I have shared a sample in the answer, but I am not sure if this is exactly what you want. It would be better for you to summarize your expectations so that we can discuss further and update a tailored answer accordingly. Please describe the detailed **conditions** **scenarios** and **dependencies** that you would expect **to run** and **not to run** each stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the requirements I summarize *so far*:

> Step #1 is triggered by default except if a PROD or SWINT variable were added during a manual build
>
> Step #2 is triggered by default except if a PROD or UNIT variable were added during a manual build
>
> Step #3 is always triggered
>
> When step2 is 'skipped' due to a PROD variable set, I would like to run step3 but it fails. To resolve this i have to replace condition by always() but in this case, the manual cancel is not taken into account.
>
> I would like to have step2 running on manual build when SWINT is added, step1 should be ignored/skipped then step2 should run and also step3. But during the run i would also allow manual 'cancel' to work....
>
> What i'm trying to do is allow user to launch a manuel build using the queue build feature, adding a variable named PROD or SWINT and set value to 1.

Here are some tips that we can take into consideration to generate the sample YAML.

- Instead of using **Step 1,2,3** to define each stage, I prefer using **Stage 1,2,3** because a `step` are usually referred as a `task` in a `job`.
- By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. If you need to refer to a stage that isn't immediately prior to the current one, you can override this automatic default by adding a `dependsOn` section to the stage. We can use `dependOn: []` for `Stage2` and `Stage3`, so that there is no dependency between stages.
- We can define variables for a YAML pipeline via the web UI and `let users override the value when running this pipeline`. In the sample, I have defined variables of `PROD` `SWINT` and `UNIT` with empty values.

  [image]

Here is the sample YAML.

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: Stage1

  condition: and( ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['SWINT'], ''))
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(PROD)
        echo $(SWINT)
      name: step1

- stage: Stage2
  dependsOn: []
  condition: and( ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['UNIT'], ''))
  jobs:
  - job: Job2
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(PROD)
        echo $(SWINT)
      name: step2

- stage: Stage3
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: Job3
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(PROD)
        echo $(SWINT)
      name: step3
```

When the pipeline is automatically triggered by any commit pushed to `main` branch, `Stage1` and `Stage2` are skipped because the conditions are evaluated and not met, as the values of variables `PROD` `SWINT` and `UNIT` are not defined; `Stage3` will continue to run even `Stage2` is skipped, because `Stage3` `dependsOn` no stages.

[image]

When I run the pipeline manually, I can replace the values of the variables `PROD`, `SWINT` and `UNIT` with `1`; hence, all the stages will be running.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, ado were updated. With stages to run it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, you can use the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) to achieve the requirement.

Step1: `condition: and( or(ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['SWINT'], '')),  eq(variables['UNIT'], ''))`

When add value to PROD or SWINT and not set value to UNIT, it will run step1.

Step2:`condition: or(ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['UNIT'], ''))`

When add value to PROD or UNIT, it will run step2.

Step3: `eq(variables['NewVariable'], 'true')`

Here is the example:

```
stages:
 - stage: Step1
   condition: and( or(ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['SWINT'], '')),  eq(variables['UNIT'], ''))
   jobs:
     - job: Step1
       steps:
        - script: echo "1"

 - stage: Step2
   condition: or(ne(variables['PROD'], ''), ne(variables['UNIT'], ''))
   jobs:
     - job: Step2
       steps:
        - script: echo "1"
  
 - stage: Step3
   condition: eq(variables['RUNSTEP3'], 'true')
   jobs:
     - job: Step3
       steps:
        - xxx
```

To let the step3 always trigger and enable manually cancel the step, you can add a new variable and use condition to judge it.

Result:

> have step2 running on manual build when SWINT is added, step1 should be ignored/skipped then step2 should run and also step3.

Variable:

[image]

Run:

[image]

**Update:**

You can cancel the stage with the **cancel** option at stage level.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.
Your solution is the same architecture than my first strategy into my question. 
The issue is that adding conditions will overwritte default value of conditions which is succeeded(). By overwrite it, you cannot use the button "cancel running build" anymore, it has no impact. And when i push it will trigg an automatic build which last 12h. Removing possibility of doing a cancel won't be acceptable.

That's why i tried a new strategy by doing something like:
stages:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], false)}}:
    - stage: Units

But using eq(..) here fail

Comment: @Ezekiel You can use the cancel option at stage level. Please check the update. It can cancel the step3 run manually.

Comment: If expression will expand at compile time.  since you are defining the variable when queuing the build, the variable will expand at runtime. So if expression will not get the correct value. You need to keep using the condition or you need to change to use parameters